# Who is the "movie star" being referred to in one of the scenes from The Social Network?

Tags: the-social-network

In [The Social Network](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt1285016%2F&ei=nQuaUL_iHIqPrgeH1YCgCQ&usg=AFQjCNFyfySm1i727h-DPs9nVk3Sq6rlDQ), which "movie star" was **Divya Narendra** referring to when he says:

> The biggest thing on a campus that included nineteen Nobel Laureates, fifteen Pultizer Prize Winners, two future Olympians, and a movie star.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had always thought that referred to Natalie Portman who graduated from Harvard in [2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalie_Portman#Education) around the time that The Social Network was to have taken place.

Out of the [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard#Alumni) on Wikipedia (which is certainly by no means authoritative or exhaustive), she's the only actor/actress that would fit that time frame.

Comment: +1. searched it through imdb and found something too. see the 8th trivia [post](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1285016/trivia)